# MySQL query gives invalid results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written a query for fetching details from my mysql table under some conditions.
My table contains rows satisfying the query but it returns an empty result set.Can anyone tell me why this happening?

Here is my query

```
select * 
from product 
where price>='0' and price<='1000' 
and internal>='0' and internal<='32' 
and screensize>='1' and screensize<='8' 
and camerares>='0' and camerares<='20' 
and p_brand like '%%%' and carrier like '%%%' 
and color like '%%%' and operating like '%%%'
```

Comment: In your fields p_brand, carrier, color and operating, do you have the % character in any of the records?

Comment: @Aiswarya,i think in mysql '%' means anything. the query gives result if i remove all other fields except'%'

Comment: if you run your query directly in phpmyadmin does it give any result?

Comment: I tried this query in phpmyadmin and asked this question

Comment: Hi @Aishvarya,Maz,I coreected my query and now its working.Dont know why.I removed quotes from price,internal etc.

Answer (score 0):

Data type of price,interval,screensize and camerares should be integer (int) in the database table. In your database, it may be varchar currently. So just change it to int, problem will resolved in seconds.